# Some questions on Pyrad

Tags: python, python-3.x, radius

I am trying to use the python library pyrad ( https://github.com/wichert/pyrad ) to build a simple Radius server. But I had some problems on it.

This is the code I am using to create a Radius server:

```
from pyrad import dictionary, packet, server

class FakeServer(server.Server):
    def _HandleAuthPacket(self, pkt):
        server.Server._HandleAuthPacket(self, pkt)

    print('Received an authentication request')
    print("Attributes: ")
    for attr in pkt.keys():
        print("%s: %s" % (attr, pkt[attr]))
    # print

    username = pkt['User-Name'][0]
    password = pkt['User-Password'][0]
    password = pkt.PwDecrypt(password)
    device_ip = pkt['NAS-IP-Address'][0]
    reply = self.CreateReplyPacket(pkt)

    # Default to refuse
    reply.code = packet.AccessReject
    reply['Reply-Message'] = 'You are unable to login'
    return self.SendReplyPacket(pkt.fd, reply)

def _HandleAcctPacket(self, pkt):
    server.Server._HandleAcctPacket(self, pkt)

    print("Received an accounting request")
    print("Attributes: ")
    for attr in pkt.keys():
        print("%s: %s" % (attr, pkt[attr]))
    # print
    reply = self.CreateReplyPacket(pkt)
    self.SendReplyPacket(pkt.fd, reply)

if __name__ == '__main':
    srv = FakeServer(dict=dictionary.Dictionary("dictionary/dictionary"))
    srv.hosts["192.168.3.183"] = server.RemoteHost("192.168.3.183",
                                               b"Kah3choteereethiejeimaeziecumi",
                                               "192.168.3.183")
    srv.BindToAddress("")
    print('Radius server is ready to start!')
    srv.Run()
```

This is the code I am using to connect the server:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyrad.client import Client
from pyrad.dictionary import Dictionary
import pyrad.packet

srv = Client(server="192.168.3.183", secret=b"Kah3choteereethiejeimaeziecumi",
             dict=Dictionary("dictionary/dictionary"))

# create request
req = srv.CreateAuthPacket(code=pyrad.packet.AccessRequest, User_Name="test",
                           NAS_IP_Address="192.168.2.101")
req["User-Password"] = req.PwCrypt("password")

# send request
reply = srv.SendPacket(req)


if reply.code == pyrad.packet.AccessAccept:
    print("access accepted")
else:
    print("access denied")

print("Attributes returned by server:")
for i in reply.keys():
    print("%s: %s" % (i, reply[i]))
```

If I start the server and connected from local, it is work!
[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlOVo.png)

But if I connect from other pc，it will time out and the pyrad.log shows this:

```
Dropping packet: Received packet from unknown host
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To be a valid RADIUS Request, a RADIUS server generally not only expects the requests to use the RADIUS Secret, but also for the requests to come from a certain IP.

Not knowing Python/Pyrad I am guessing that at least one of the IPs in the following part of your server-code should be the client-IP, from which you are attempting to send the request from:

```
server.RemoteHost("192.168.3.183", b"Kah3choteereethiejeimaeziecumi", "192.168.3.183")
```

Check the documentation of Pyrad, it should say something about Client IPs.

Answer (score 0):

I found this while looking for the answer myself.  I eventually fumbled through the code library and got a response from the server.  For background, I'm setting this up for ryu-controller.  My server is FreeRADIUS and they are on separate VMs.  I've been testing with the radclient utility - so I already knew the server worked.

On this line:

```
srv = Client(server="192.168.3.183", secret=b"Kah3choteereethiejeimaeziecumi", dict=Dictionary("dictionary/dictionary"))
```

make sure that server="192.168.3.183" is the IP of your server.  When I initially looked at this code I thought I had to include the clients IP but I remembered radtest doesn't require this - so that prompted me to change the parameter.  Also I removed NAS_IP_Address from the CreateAuthPacket method/function.

Your server code seems to be listing 192.168.3.183 as the client.  So your Client Object is setting itself as the "RADIUS" server.  I would recommend setting up [FreeRADIUS](https://freeradius.org/) and using the radtest/radclient utility (it is a part of FreeRADIUS) and test out each piece of code separately.  [Quick Setup Guide](https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Basic-configuration-HOWTO)

Hope this helps.